# mysql: union re-use subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, union

There is a table:

```
ID        City      

1          Toronto
2          Toronto
3          Toronto
4          Toronto
5          NY
6          NY
```

How to get the following table:

```
City    Total

NULL    6
Toronto 4
NY      2
```

I plan to use `union`:

```
(select city, count(*) as total from tbl group by city)
union
(select null, count(*) as total from tbl)
```

Is it possible to use something like to reuse the subquery:

```
(select city, count(*) as total from tbl group by city) tmp
union
(select null, count(*) as tmp from tbl)
```

Or sql already optimizes

```
(select city, count(*) as total from tbl group by city)
union
(select null, count(*) as total from tbl)
```

?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse the the query but you could use a view for reuse the code

```
  create view  my_view as 
  select city, count(*) as total 
  from tbl group by city
```

once created  the view  you could

```
  select  city, total 
  from my_view 
  union  
  select  null, sum(total)
  from my_view
```

Answer (score 3):

In at least MySQL 5.5 and newer, you can use the [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier to get a total sum of the grouped elements without an extra query;

```
SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS total FROM tbl GROUP BY city WITH ROLLUP

city      total
---------------
NY        2
Toronto   4
(null)    6
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53b82e3/5).

Answer (score 0):

1) Take aliases are only visible to join members and subquery. Not to union members.

2) The query as you wrote it makes little sense: aliasing tmp to a table then a scalar?

To achieve what you want to achieve, you can try using CTEs:

```
WITH tmp AS (SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS cnt GROUP BY city) 
SELECT * FROM tmp UNION SELECT null, SUM(cnt) FROM tmp
```

I don't know what the performance difference would be. If you have an index on `city`, I doubt you will see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You use `WITH ROLLUP` in a subquery and then arrange the ordering in the outer query to put the rollup record on top:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS total FROM mytable GROUP BY city WITH ROLLUP) x 
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN city IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    city
```

If you are planning to order the results by descending total, that's even simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS total FROM mytable GROUP BY city WITH ROLLUP) x 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wHGS9PW9znLbGvhqW4rzEX/0)**:

```
| city    | total |
| ------- | ----- |
|         | 6     |
| Toronto | 4     |
| NY      | 2     |
```